# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - Call to constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just begun learning python and trying to implement a very basic program. Here is the code

```
from com.gs.entities import Employee
from _datetime import datetime, timedelta


class Branch:

    def __init__(self, branchName):
        self.branchName = branchName
        self.startTime = datetime.now()
        self.endTime = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours = 9)
        self.employees = []
        for i in range(0, 10):
            if(i < 6):
                self.employees.append(Employee(i, str(i), "Cashier"))
            elif(i < 8):
                self.employees.append(Employee(i, str(i), "Loan Officers"))
            elif(i == 8):
                self.employees.append(Employee(i, str(i), "Deputy Manager"))
            elif(i == 9):
                self.employees.append(Employee(i, str(i), "Manager"))
        
    def startOperation(self):
        print("Starting operation at " + self.startTime)

    def endOperation(self):
        print("Starting operation at " + self.endTime)


b = Branch("CP")
print(b.employees)
```

Here is the code for Employee class

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, employeeId, employeeName, employeeRole):
        self.employeeId = employeeId
        self.employeeName = employeeName
        self.employeeRole = employeeRole
```

Now when I run Branch class it throws the following error

```
self.employees.append(Employee(i, str(i), "Cashier"))
```

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

If I change the line to self.employees.append(i), the error goes away. What I want to do is create a list of employees of that branch.

Comment: Does `Employee` happen to be in a file called `Employee.py`?  You may need `from com.gs.entities.Employee import Employee`.

Comment: yes Employee class is in Employee.py, typical java based approach. What you suggested , I will check and get back.

Comment: @TimRoberts - What you suggested worked, whats the rationale behind this ?

Comment: `com.gs.entities.Employee` is the name of a module.  So, when you do `from com.gs.entities import Employee`, that's imports the module called "Employee"  Within that module, there's a class called `Employee`.  So, you COULD have said `Employee.Employee(i, str(i), "Cashier")`.  This is the same as the standard `array` module.  You can say `import array` and `x = array.array('h')`, or you can say `from array import array` (from module array, import the class array) and `x = array('h')`.

Answer (score 1):

I put everything on the same file and it worked fine for me. The output is a bit weird since you are not implementing a toString() method to your object yet, but your employees list gets appended just fine:

```
from _datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Employee:

    def __init__(self, employeeId, employeeName, employeeRole):
        self.employeeId = employeeId
        self.employeeName = employeeName
        self.employeeRole = employeeRole
    def toString(self):
        return......      
        
        
class Branch:

    def __init__(self, branchName):
        self.branchName = branchName
        self.startTime = datetime.now()
        self.endTime = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours = 9)
        self.employees = []
        for i in range(0, 10):
            if(i < 6):
                self.employees.append(Employee(i, str(i), "Cashier"))
            elif(i < 8):
                self.employees.append(Employee(i, str(i), "Loan Officers"))
            elif(i == 8):
                self.employees.append(Employee(i, str(i), "Deputy Manager"))
            elif(i == 9):
                self.employees.append(Employee(i, str(i), "Manager"))
        
    def startOperation(self):
        print("Starting operation at " + self.startTime)

    def endOperation(self):
        print("Starting operation at " + self.endTime)


b = Branch("CP")

[print(i) for i in b.employees]
```

**Output:**

```
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62a58>
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62a90>
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62b70>
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62be0>
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62c50>
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62cc0>
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62d30>
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62da0>
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62e48>
<__main__.Employee object at 0x7ffa98a62eb8>
```

Comment: I was using java based approach. Employee class in Employee.py.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that.  You just need to remember that the module Employee contains a class Employee, and those are two different things.

Comment: `toString` is Java; you want `__str__` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Roberts commented, the Module `Employee.py` and a class `Employee` within it are different, and you have to refer to the class itself.

This sort of naming is fairly common in Python libraries - `time.time()`, `datetime.datetime`, `PIL.Image.Image`, etc are a few more examples I can recall immediately.

In general, if you want to quickly check whether the thing you're importing is a package, module, class, function, etc...; you can open the python shell and check what those identifiers refer to :

```py
>>> from com.gs.entities import Employee
>>> Employee
<module 'com.gs.entities.Employee' from '/full/path/to/com.gs/entities/Employee.py'>
>>> Employee.Employee
<class 'com.gs.entities.Employee.Employee'>
>>> from com.gs.entities.Employee import Employee as Emp
>>> Emp
<class 'com.gs.entities.Employee.Employee'>
```

or some similar output